# Ignore Base Class Properties in Json.NET Serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have the following class structure:

```
[JsonObject]
public class Polygon : IEnumerable<Point>
{
    public List<Point> Vertices { get; set; }
    public AxisAlignedRectangle Envelope { get; set; }
}

public class AxisAlignedRectangle : Polygon {
    public double Left { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I am serializing the `Polygon` class, but when I do, I get a `JsonSerializationException`, with the message

> Self referencing loop detected for property 'Envelope' with type 'MyNamespace.AxisAlignedRectangle'.

If I add `[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]` ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18223985/960115)) to AxisAlignedRectangle, the code runs fine, but I get an auto-assigned $id field in each instance of AxisAlignedRectangle, and a $ref field when that instance is re-referenced.  For example, when I serialize a polygon, I get:

```
{
    Vertices: [ ... ],
    Envelope: {
        $id: '1',
        Left: -5,
        ...
        Vertices: [ ... ],
        Envelope: {
            $ref: '1'
        }
    }
}
```

My desire is to remove the Polygon properties entirely when I serialize an AxisAlignedRectangle.  I tried adding a `DataContractAttribute` to the AxisAlignedRectangle class (along with appropriate `DataMemberAttribute` attributes), but all the properties of Polygon were still being serialized.  This was unexpected, since there is an example in the [Json.NET documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm) that appears to indicate such an approach should work.

Does anyone know a way to explicitly remove (most importantly) the Envelope property from the resulting Json.NET serialization, when the type being serialized is AxisAlignedRectangle?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [conditional property serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm), by defining your classes like this:

```
[JsonObject]
public class Polygon : IEnumerable<Point>
{
    public List<Point> Vertices { get; set; }
    public AxisAlignedRectangle Envelope { get; set; }

    public virtual bool ShouldSerializeEnvelope()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class AxisAlignedRectangle : Polygon
{
    public double Left { get; set; }
    ...

    public override bool ShouldSerializeEnvelope()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have posted the full solution at:
https://github.com/thiagoavelino/VisualStudio_C/blob/master/VisualStudio_C/StackOverFlow/ParsingJason/EnvelopePolygonProblem.cs

Comment: Not work when you inherit from a third-party class.

Answer (score 29):

Most simple way to do it is simply decorate the AxisAlignedRectangle object with `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]`.

In a sentence, it will serialize only properties decorated with [JsonProperty] attribute.
You can read more here: [MemberSerialization Enumeration](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MemberSerialization.htm).

Another option is to decorate the Polygon properties with [JsonIgnoreAttribute Class](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm).

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I only want to disable serialization of Polygon.Envelope in 1 of the N subclasses of Polygon.  To get your suggestion to work, I would have to mark Polygon.Envelope virtual, then override it in AxisAlignedRectangle, just to add JsonIgnoreAttribute.  Even if that works, I think the solution marked as answer is cleaner, since the code makes it clear that only the serialization of its members can be changed, not their underlying behavior.

Comment: Saved my day , Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I've run into the same thing. The `JsonIgnoreAttribute` is a good solution if a certain property should always be ingored and you have access to the class containing the property. But if you want to determine which properties should be serialized at serialization-time, you can use a ContractResolver.

Here's an implementation that allows you to serialize properties starting with the most derived class and stopping at a given base class. In my case, I wanted to serialize the properties of my custom CMS (EPiServer) page types, but didn't want to serialize all of the built-in properties of the page classes.

```
public class DerivedClassContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private Type _stopAtBaseType;

    public DerivedClassContractResolver(Type stopAtBaseType) 
    {
        _stopAtBaseType = stopAtBaseType;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        Type originalType = GetOriginalType(type);
        IList<JsonProperty> defaultProperties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        List<string> includedProperties = Utilities.GetPropertyNames(originalType, _stopAtBaseType);

        return defaultProperties.Where(p => includedProperties.Contains(p.PropertyName)).ToList();
    }

    private Type GetOriginalType(Type type)
    {
        Type originalType = type;

        //If the type is a dynamic proxy, get the base type
        if (typeof(Castle.DynamicProxy.IProxyTargetAccessor).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            originalType = type.BaseType ?? type;

        return originalType;
    }
}

public class Utilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a list of all public instance properties of a given class type
    /// excluding those belonging to or inherited by the given base type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The Type to get property names for</param>
    /// <param name="stopAtType">A base type inherited by type whose properties should not be included.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<string> GetPropertyNames(Type type, Type stopAtBaseType)
    {
        List<string> propertyNames = new List<string>();

        if (type == null || type == stopAtBaseType) return propertyNames; 

        Type currentType = type;

        do
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = currentType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                if (!propertyNames.Contains(property.Name))
                    propertyNames.Add(property.Name);

            currentType = currentType.BaseType;
        } while (currentType != null && currentType != stopAtBaseType);

        return propertyNames;
    }
}
```

This let's me do something like this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(page, new JsonSerializerSettings() 
    { 
         ContractResolver = new DerivedClassContractResolver(typeof(EPiServer.Core.PageData)) 
    }));
```

to get the properties I have defined on my own class(es) without getting the slew of properties inherited from EPiServer.Core.PageData. Note: You don't need the `GetOriginalType()` code if you're not using the [Castle DynamicProxy project](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) (which the EPiServer CMS does.)

Comment: Brillant, `ContractResolver` was exacly what I needed and what I thought the JsonSerializer is missing. Soo handy!

Comment: Great solution! Thanks for sharing it :)

Answer (score 0):

In WPF its common to want to ignore `Observables`

```
public class TypeOnlyContractResolver<T> : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        property.ShouldSerialize = instance =>
        {
            return !property.DeclaringType.AssemblyQualifiedName.Contains("Observable");
        };

        property.ShouldDeserialize = instance =>
        {
            return !property.DeclaringType.AssemblyQualifiedName.Contains("Observable");
        };

        return property;
    }
}
```

This will ignore anything with the base class `ObservableObject` etc.