# Generate JSON Schema for only required properties

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

We are using Newtonsoft JSON (C#, .Net Framework 4.5) and I would like generate a JSON schema based on a few properties of a class which has category attribute set. How do I achieve this?

Example:

```
class School
{
    [Editable(false)]
    [DisplayName("Student")]
    [Category("Student")]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    [Editable(true)]
    [Range(0, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]
    [Category("Student")]
    public int Id { get; set; } = 10;

    [Editable(false)]
    [DisplayName("ParentName")]
    [Category("Student")]
    public string ParentName { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty("ParentPhone", Required = Required.Default)]
    [PhoneMask("999-999-9999",
        ErrorMessage = "{0} value does not match the mask {1}.")]
    [Category("Student")]
    public string Phone;

    [Editable(true)]
    [Category("Staff")]
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }

    [Editable(true)]
    [Range(0, 10000, ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]
    [DefaultValue(5000)]
    [Category("Staff")]
    public int Salary { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [Category("Student")]
    public bool AvailingTransport { get; set; } = true;
}
```

From the above example, I would like to generate JSON schema for only those properties which has category attribute set to student only.

I tried something like below, which didn't work.

```
abstract class SelectedAttributesSerializationProvider : JSchemaGenerationProvider
{
    public override JSchema GetSchema(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context)
    {
        var type = context.ObjectType;
        JSchema schema = null;

        var generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
        PropertyInfo[] myMembers = type.GetProperties();
       
        var categoryAttributes = myMembers.Where(c => c.CustomAttributes.Any(p => p.AttributeType.Name == "CategoryAttribute"));

        foreach(PropertyInfo categoryAttribute in categoryAttributes)
        {
            foreach(CustomAttributeData customAttributeData in categoryAttribute.GetCustomAttributesData())
            {
                if(customAttributeData.AttributeType.Name == "CategoryAttribute")
                {
                    generator.GenerationProviders.Add(this);
                }
            }           
        }
       
        schema = generator.Generate(type);
        return ModifySchema(schema, context);
    }

    public abstract JSchema ModifySchema(JSchema schema, JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context);

}
```

Comment: instead of [Editable(false)], if you want to make non-editable a field, you should use ReadOnly like this:
 [ReadOnly(true)]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude property from Json Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169648/how-to-exclude-property-from-json-serialization)

Comment: @PoulBak - I don't think so.  Querent is trying to generate a customized [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/) for their model.  System.Text.Json doesn't support schema generation at all so they are using [Json.NET Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) instead.

Comment: PHONE: [JsonProperty("ParentPhone", Required = Required.Default)]
 [RegularExpression("\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid phone no.")]
 [Category("Student")]
 public string Phone {get;set;}

Comment: check example of schema generator provider https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/CreateCustomProvider.htm

Comment: be aware of known issue: The free-quota limit of 10 schema generations per hour has been reached. Please visit http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema to upgrade to a commercial license

Comment: @dbc: The accepted answer uses `DefaultContractResolver` just like your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a custom `JSchemaGenerationProvider`, it will be easier to accomplish what you need with a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) that only returns the properties marked with the required category.

First define the following contract resolver that removes all properties other than those with the required [`CategoryAttribute.Category`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute.category) metadata value:

```
public class CategoryOnlyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    readonly bool alwaysIncludeConstructorParameters = false;
    readonly string category;

    public CategoryOnlyContractResolver(string category, bool alwaysIncludeConstructorParameters = false) : base() 
    {
        this.category = category;
        this.alwaysIncludeConstructorParameters = alwaysIncludeConstructorParameters; 
    }

    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
        for (int i = contract.Properties.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var p = contract.Properties[i];
            if (!p.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.CategoryAttribute), true).Cast<CategoryAttribute>().Any(c => c.Category == category)
                || (alwaysIncludeConstructorParameters && contract.CreatorParameters.GetClosestMatchProperty(p.PropertyName) != null))
                contract.Properties.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        return contract;
    }
}
```

Now you can generate your schema as follows:

```
var studentGenerator = new JSchemaGenerator();
studentGenerator.ContractResolver = new CategoryOnlyContractResolver("Student");

var studentSchema = studentGenerator.Generate(typeof(School));
```

Notes:

- The contract resolver will optionally retain properties that are also constructor parameters.  (This does not apply to the example shown in your question.)
- One advantage of this approach is that you can later reuse the same contract resolver to serialize only the properties with the required category as shown in [Serialization using ContractResolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TKIoTi).

Comment: Thanks for the solution and for a quick reply. But this solution has a problem. What if there is another property as below at the bottom of the class? This is throwing an error as "System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added.'".

[ReadOnly(true)]
[Category("Student")]
public bool AvailingTransport { get; set; } = true;

Comment: I believe we are getting the opposite schema rather than the expected schema?

Comment: I believe we are getting the opposite schema rather than the expected schema? The actual schema we are getting is 

{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "TeacherName": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    "Salary": {
      "type": "integer",
      "default": 5000,
      "minimum": 0.0,
      "maximum": 10000.0
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "TeacherName",
    "Salary"
  ]
}

Comment: Corrected the issue as the issue was in the below "IF" statement. It had double "NOT" at the begining of the IF statement and required was only one?
if (!!p.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.CategoryAttribute), true).Cast<CategoryAttribute>().Any(c => c.Category == category)
     || (alwaysIncludeConstructorParameters && contract.CreatorParameters.GetClosestMatchProperty(p.PropertyName) != null))
     contract.Properties.RemoveAt(i);

Comment: I have one more query here, what if I need to create a subobjects of "Student" and "Staff" in the main schema object?

Comment: @Developer - I am not entirely sure what your comment means but if you just want to ignore properties other than `"Student"` and `"Staff"` by name, you can also do that with a custom contract resolver, see [Newtonsoft JSON - Way of ignoring properties without adding `[JsonIgnore]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45010583).  But beyond that the format for questions is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735) so I would recommend asking a new question with a [mcve] that includes your C# model and required schema.