# How to ignore ObjectSchema and Ream properties when serializing a realmObject

Tags: c#, uwp, realm

I m trying to serialize a RealmObject in my uwp project and I would like to know if there is any way to  to ignore ObjectSchema and Ream properties when serializing a realmObject ? I tried to create a constuctor to avoid copying these two properties but It doesn't worked for me.

This is my object :

```
public class Sector : RealmObject, NodeBase
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    [Ignored]
    public Dictionary<string, string> title { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Dictionary Title { get; set; }
    public int position { get; set; }
    public bool template_is_carousel { get; set; }
    public bool isVisible { get; set; }
    public IList<string> filter { get; }
    [Ignored]
    public DisplayType display_type { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string DisplayType { get; set; }
    public int parent_id { get; set; }
    public string parent_type { get; set; }
    public string image_url { get; set; }
    public string banner_color { get; set; }
    public int template_rows { get; set; } = 3;
    public int template_columns { get; set; } = 2;

    public Sector(Sector sector)
    {
        this.id = sector.id;
        this.key = sector.key;
        this.Title = sector.Title;
        this.title = sector.title;
        this.position = sector.position;
        this.template_is_carousel = sector.template_is_carousel;
        this.isVisible = sector.isVisible;
        this.filter = sector.filter;
        this.display_type = sector.display_type;
        this.DisplayType = sector.DisplayType;
        this.parent_id = sector.parent_id;
        this.parent_type = sector.parent_type;
        this.image_url = sector.image_url;
        this.banner_color = sector.banner_color;
        this.template_rows = sector.template_rows;
        this.template_columns = sector.template_columns;
    }

    public Sector()
    {
    }
}
```

And this is how I m serializing my object :

```
private string serializeParameter(object parameter)
    {
         return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameter); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Serialization in [`Json.NET`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) will serialize base class properties by default. The `Sector` class inherit from `RealmObject`  class, then when serializing `Sector` object, all the base properties in the parent class `RealmObject` will be serialized.

To resolve this, you could try to use [`[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonObjectAttributeOptIn.htm) attribute, in that case, properties without specify `[JsonProperty]` will not be serialized. For example, the following code will only serialize `parent_type` property,

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Sector : RealmObject
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string parent_type { get; set; } 
}
```

Actually the simply way is to add  `[JsonIgnore]` attribute for the properties in the parent class. But it looks like you are using a third package that you could not change the parent class `RealmObject`.

More details please reference 
[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104335/ignore-base-class-properties-in-json-net-serialization).

To use which way is based on your requirements, you could also try to serialize it by [Json relative APIs in UWP app](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Json) without using the `Json.Net`. For example:

```
 var jsonstring= Stringify();

 public string Stringify()
 { 
     JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
     jsonObject["parent_type "] = JsonValue.CreateStringValue("test"); 
     return jsonObject.Stringify();
 }
```