# C# json custom serializing

Tags: c#, json

I have created a custom label object in c# and I need to make json object from this object.
But I have derived the Label from the 'Label' control to custom label object.
After serializing custom label object, json is getting filled with label properties.
But, I don't need it. I need to pass only the custom label object.

This is custom label :

```
public class customLabel:Label
{

        public string X { get; set; }

        public string Y { get; set; }

        public string H { get; set; }

        public string W { get; set; }

        public string FontName { get; set; }

        public string FontSize { get; set; }

        public string Type { get; set; }

        public string Align { get; set; }

        public string _Text { get; set; }


}
```

I am using  `Newtonsoft.Json`  for json serializng

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: how can i only pass custom label object for serializng? @SebastianHofmann

Comment: yeah, but your object inherits from `Label` so, it is a label too.

Comment: @Jodrell can i only pass this values to json?

Comment: @DanialDP what value do you mean by `this values`? You can pass *any* object to JSON.NET. Objects will always be serialized as dictionaries. Did you *try* it? What code did you use? What did you get and what did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [custom `JsonConvertor`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) that includes the properties you want.

Then pass it to `SerializeObject` to control the serialization.

```
string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                     customLabel,
                     Formatting.Indented,
                     new CustomLabelConverter(typeof(CustomLabel)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [Ignore Base Class Properties in Json.NET Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104335/ignore-base-class-properties-in-json-net-serialization)

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class customLabel:Label
{
    [JsonProperty("X")]
    public string X { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Y")]
    public string Y { get; set; }

    ...
    public string H { get; set; }

    public string W { get; set; }

    public string FontName { get; set; }

    public string FontSize { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Align { get; set; }

    public string _Text { get; set; }

}
```

but you need to put JsonProperty to all any property you need to serialize it

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
customLabel yourLabel = new customLabel();

yourLabel.X = 50;
yourLabel.Y = 20;
//....

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourLabel);
//output contains the serialized object

customLabel deserializedLabel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<customLabel>(output);
```

edit: 
Change your class to this:

```
[DataContract]
public class customLabel:Label
{
     [DataMember]
     public string X { get; set; }
     [DataMember]    
     public string Y { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public string H { get; set; }
     [DataMember]    
     public string W { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public string FontName { get; set; }
     [DataMember]   
     public string FontSize { get; set; }
     [DataMember]  
     public string Type { get; set;
     [DataMember]
     public string Align { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public string _Text { get; set; }
}
```

Now only the properties with the attribute [DataMember] should be included

And take a look at the documentation: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Comment: but its pass label properties.i just wanna pass custom label values!

Comment: sorry i misunderstood you.
I added the class definition